# Proving a number divisor using modular arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The exercise question is to show that:

$2^{3n} + 91{n^2} - 1$ is divisible by $7$ Or $2^{3n} + 91{n^2} - 1 \equiv 0    \pmod 7 $ using modular arithmetic.

So I know that $2^{3n} = 8^n$ and I can show that

$8 \equiv 1 \pmod7$ and therefore ${8^n} \equiv 1^n \pmod7$

But I'm at a bit of a loss figuring and how to add the other numbers in there, so I'm at a bit of a loss on this one.

Comment: [Are you two on the same class?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1913853/131263)

Comment: Yeah quite possibly. Didn't see that.